# Asymptotic growth of the solutions of $ n_1 + 2 n_2+\dotsb+k n_k=k$, $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'd like to know the cardinal of the solutions of the equation of $ n_1 + 2 n_2+\dotsb+k n_k=k$,  $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$, or just an asymptotic approximation.

Comment: This is the partition function $p(k)$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory) .  The question of establishing its asymptotics was famously solved by Hardy and Ramanujan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas

Comment: p.s. more generally, for any question of the form "I'd like to know about the following integer sequence", the standard thing to do is consult the OEIS: https://oeis.org/

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan It's trivial: pick $n_2,\dots,n_k$ arbitrarily, and choose $n_1$ accordingly.

Comment: To add some detail to Terry's comment, what you're supposed to do is compute the first few entries of the sequence by hand, enter them into the search box, and try to check that one of the results that comes up matches your sequence.

Comment: Maybe i don’t understand but in the website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory) they are speaking about the function p(n) which grives the possible cases for the of a positive integer which are far more then my question

Comment: Can you give a concrete value of $k$, the value which you expect, and the differing value of $p(k)$?